# Setting special methods using setattr()

Tags: python, introspection, setattr

Is it possible to dynamically assign special methods, such as `__getitem__`, to a class instance using `setattr()`?  For example, if I have this:

```
class Example (object):
    pass
```

And then try this:

```
>>> example = Example()
>>> setattr(example, '__getitem__', lambda x: 1)
```

I get this:

```
>>> example['something']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Example' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

But of course this works just fine:

```
>>> example.__getitem__('something')
1
```

There's obviously something going on here that I don't understand regarding how Python does method lookups for this sort of thing.  Do these methods have to be set on the *class*, rather than on the instance?

**UPDATE**:

So, I should make it clear than I know I can see this on the `Example` class...I was hoping there was a way to set them *per-instance*, but the consensus I'm seeing so far is You Can't Do That.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that `__getitem__()` is defined at a class-level, not at instance-level:

```
>>> class Example (object):
...     pass
... 
>>> example = Example()
>>> setattr(Example, '__getitem__', lambda x, y: 1)
>>> example['something']
1
```

If you need it to be instance-specific:

```
>>> class Example(object):
...     def __getitem__(self, item):
...         return self._getitem(item)
... 
>>> example = Example()
>>> setattr(example, '_getitem', lambda x: 1)
>>> example['something']
1
>>> example2 = Example()
>>> setattr(example2, '_getitem', lambda x: 2)
>>> example['something']
1
>>> example2['something']
2
```

Comment: Hmm...but this would then affect all instances of `Example`, rather than just the specific instance.  Back to the drawing board for me, I guess.

Comment: @larsks It's pretty trivial to make `__getitem__()` call a function on the instance. I'll add an example.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try monkeypatching the class, not the instance?

```
>>> example = Example()
>>> setattr(Example, '__getitem__', lambda self,x: 1)
```